# Problema com validação de varios formulários com ajax e php

Tags: php, html5, ajax

No meu site eu tenho vários formulários: form de filtro de imóveis, form de contato, form fale com o presidente e o form de sugestões.

Existe alguma forma de recuperar todos os formulários menos o formulario de filtro de imóveis e enviar para urls diferentes no ajax?

No código abaixo estou trabalhando somente com um formulário.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //Forms
        var formMsg     = $('.load');
        var button      = $('#btnEnvia'); 
        var forms       = $('form');
        var has_error   = 0 ;
        var nome        = $("#nome").val();
        var msg         = $("#msg").val();
        var email       = $("#email").val();
        var telefone    = $("#telefone").val();
        var atpos       = email.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos      = email.lastIndexOf(".");

        var urlpost = 'tpl/form-contato.php';
        var urlpost2 = 'tpl/form-presidente.php';
        var urlpost3 = 'tpl/form-contato.php';

        formMsg.hide();
        button.attr("type", "submit");
        forms.submit(function(){
            formMsg.fadeOut("fast");
            return false;
        });

        function carregando(){
            formMsg.empty().html('<p><img src="img/load.gif" width="22">  Agurade enviando...</p>').fadeIn("fast");
        }

        function errosend(){
            formMsg.empty().html('<p class="danger">Erro inesperado, contate o administrador.</p>').fadeIn("fast");
        }

        //Genericas
        function errdados( mensagem ){
            formMsg.empty().html('<p class="bg-danger">'+mensagem+'</p>').fadeIn("fast");
        }
        function sucesso( mensagem ){
            formMsg.empty().html('<p class="success">'+mensagem+'</p>').fadeIn("fast");
        }

        $.ajaxSetup({
            url:        urlpost,
            type:       'POST',
            beforeSend: carregando,
            error:      errosend
        });


        var formContato = $('form[name="contato"]');

        formContato.submit(function(){
            var dados = $(this).serialize();
            var acao = "&acao=enviar"
            if ($("#nome").val().length == 0) {
                has_error = 1 ;
                $('#nome').css({
                    "background-color": "rgba(248, 116, 116, 0.52)"
            });
            }
            if($("#email").val().length == 0) {
                has_error = 1 ;
                $('#email').css({
                    "background-color": "rgba(248, 116, 116, 0.52)"
                });
            }
            if(atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= email.length) {
                has_error = 1 ;
                $('#email').css({
                    "background-color": "rgba(248, 116, 116, 0.52)"
                });
            }
            if($("#msg").val().length == 0) {
                has_error = 1 ;
                $('#msg').css({
                    "background-color": "rgba(248, 116, 116, 0.52)"
                });
            }
            if(has_error == 0 ) {
                $.ajax({
                    data: dados+acao,
                    success: function(resposta){
                        sucesso("Enviado com sucesso!");
                        $('#btnEnvia').val('ENVIADO!');
                         $('#btnEnvia').css({
                            "background-color": "#00E681"
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Você que fazer uma função que seja reaproveitada para todos os formulários? É isso? Ou você quer enviar todos os formulários quando o utilizador apertar "enviar"?

Comment: Você pode passar em um `input hidden` com nome `forms[]` informando em qual form será executado a submissão e capturar a URL como um valor: `var urlpost = $('#form_execute').val()`. E fazer um for no elemento  para executar cada url independentemente.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes, seria mais ou menos isso, recuperar somente alguns formulários tratar os dados de forma genérica como success, error e complete e se os campos estão vazios ou não e enviar a ação para url diferentes.

Answer (score 1):

Para **Jquery** **1.5+**, você pode ultilizar o  objeto:

```
$.when($.ajax(), [...]).then(function(resultado){},[...]);
```

**Exemplo:**

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="enviar" />

$('#button').click(function() {
    $.when(
        $.ajax({
            url: 'tpl/form-contato.php',
            success: function(data) {
                alert('Deu certo!')
            }
        }),
        $.ajax({
            url: 'tpl/form-presidente.php',
            success: function(data) {
                alert('Deu certo!')
            }
        }),
        $.ajax({
            url: 'tpl/form-contato.php',
            success: function(data) {
                alert('Deu certo!')
            }
        })
    ).then( function(){
        alert('Deu TUDO certo!');
    });
});
```

> Assim, um único Deferred é passado para jQuery.when();

[Fonte](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

Comment: Muito legal esse recurso, mas ele envia as ações para todas as urls ao mesmo tempo, ou ele percorre os formulários, identifica o formulário e envia para a url que eu atribuir a ele?

Comment: Exatamente o que você disse por último. Veja a documentação em "FONTE".